# Why the returning object of the orm function is limited to 100?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, orm

In a Node.js project I'm using [oracle-orm-zn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracle-orm-zn) for the communication with my Oracle database.

At some point I call the function `findAllandCount()` to get all the records in a table:

```
...
tipm.findAllandCount(params).then(function (r) {
    if (r.all > 0) {
        locals.data.righe = r.rows;

        console.log("+allRows:", r.all);
        console.log("+NumRows:", r.rows.length);
    }
...
```

Where `params` is the Object:

```
// var params = { attributes: viewOrder, order: sortOrder, limit: 9999 };
var params = { attributes: viewOrder, order: sortOrder};
```

As indicated in [findAllandCount() documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracle-orm-zn#modelfindallandcount) without limit (or with limit = 9999) I should get all the records of the table!
Instead I get only 100 records, as I can see from the `console.log("+NumRows:", r.rows.length)` statement.

The statement `console.log("+allRows:", r.all)` give me the correct number of records.

I thought so that the problem is in `findAllandCount()` function of the module, that is:

```
Model.prototype.findAllandCount = function(options){
    var pro = Q.defer(), self = this;
    var sql_count = 'select count(*) as count from ' + self.table_name;
    var sql = 'select * from (select rownum rownum_,t.* from ', start = 0, end = 100;
    if(!options){
        sql += self.table_name+ ' where rownum <= ' + end ;
    }else{
        sql += '(';
        var _col = '', _tab = '', _where = '';
        var makeCTW = function(opt, par_tn){
            if(!opt.model ) { pro.reject(ecode.lack_para());return pro.promise;}
            var sub_tn = opt.model.table_name;
            //make column sql (has ',' last)
            if(opt.attributes && opt.attributes.length){
                for(var i=0;i<opt.attributes.length;i++){
                    _col += par_tn? sub_tn+'.'+opt.attributes[i]+' as '+sub_tn+'#'+opt.attributes[i]+',' : sub_tn+'.'+opt.attributes[i]+',';
                }
            }else{
                if(par_tn){
                    for(var colkey in opt.model.col_def){
                        _col += sub_tn+'.'+colkey+' as '+sub_tn+'#'+colkey+',';
                    }
                }else
                    _col += sub_tn+'.*,';
            }
            //make table sql (has ',' front)
            if(opt.notRequired && par_tn){
                if(!opt.use||!opt.on){ pro.reject(ecode.lack_para());return pro.promise;}
                _tab += ' left join '+sub_tn+' on '+par_tn+'.'+opt.use+'='+sub_tn+'.'+opt.on;
            }else{
                _tab += ','+sub_tn;
            }
            //make where sql (has ' and ' last)
            if(opt.where){
                _where += lib.whereObjToSqlStr(opt.where,opt.model.col_def,sub_tn)+' and ';
            }
            if(!opt.notRequired && par_tn){
                if(!opt.use||!opt.on){
                    pro.reject(ecode.lack_para());return pro.promise;
                }
                _where += par_tn+'.'+opt.use+'='+sub_tn+'.'+opt.on+' and ';
            }
            if(opt.include && opt.include.length){
                for(var j= 0; j<opt.include.length; j++) makeCTW(opt.include[j],sub_tn);
            }
        };
        options.model = self;
        makeCTW(options);
        sql += 'select '+_col.substring(0,_col.length-1)+' from '+_tab.substring(1,_tab.length)+
            (_where==''?'':(' where '+_where.substring(0,_where.length-4)))+
            ') t where rownum<='+end+' ) where rownum_>='+start;
        if(options.order){
            if(typeof(options.order) == 'string') sql += ' order by '+options.order;
            else if(options.order.length){
                sql += ' order by ';
                for(var i= 0,l= options.order.length;i<l;i++) sql += options.order[i]+',';
                sql = sql.substring(0,sql.length-1);
            }
        }
    }
    self.orm.getCon().then(function(con){
        var _pro = Q.defer();
        con.execute(sql_count,{},self.orm.opt,function(e,r){
            if(e) _pro.reject({c:con,e:'FindAllandCount count error: '+ e.message});
            else _pro.resolve({c:con,r: r.rows[0].COUNT});
        });
        return _pro.promise;
    }).then(function(res){
        var con = res.c, count = res.r;
        var _pro = Q.defer();
        con.execute(sql,{},self.orm.opt,function(e,r){
            if(e) _pro.reject({c:con,e:'FindAllandCount select error: '+ e.message});
            else _pro.resolve({c:con,r: r.rows.length? r.rows: null, count: count});
        });
        return _pro.promise;
    }).then(function(res){
        res.c.release();
        if(res.r && res.r.length){
            for(var i= 0,l=res.r.length;i<l;i++){
                delete res.r[i].ROWNUM_;
                for(var k in res.r[i]){
                    var ks = k.split('#');
                    if(ks.length ==2 && ks[0] && ks[1]){
                        if(!res.r[i][ks[0]]) res.r[i][ks[0]] = {};
                        res.r[i][ks[0]][ks[1]] = res.r[i][k];
                        delete res.r[i][k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pro.resolve({
            all: res.count,
            rows: res.r
        });
    }).catch(function(e){
        e.c.release();
        pro.reject(ecode.sql_execute(e.e));
    });
    return pro.promise;
};
```

And, unless my mistakes, everything seems to depend on that `end = 100`. Which does not seem to be set dynamically.

Is this really the case?
Should I open an issue on the github page of oracle-orm-zn?

Can I do some more tests? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked and that library hasn't been updated for years. They are using node-oracledb 1.13.1 (current version is 4.0.1). Consider dropping the ORM and just using the latest version of the driver. See this series for help getting going: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Answer (score 0):

i think, this is a some kind of bug, becouse there no check for option "limit" in code of the function, and they use variables "start" and "end" when they build their sql request and those variables aren't changed dynamically, you may test this, just set the "limit" as some random number